# error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, methods, parameters, scope, return

```
public static void main(String args [])
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number = 0;

    do{
        System.out.print("Which Fibonacci Number would you like? ");
        number = in.nextInt();
    }while(number < 0 || number > 71);

    System.out.printf("Fibonacci #%d is %d\n",number, fibcalc(fib));

}

 public static double fibcalc(int number)
{
    double prevNumber1 = 0;
    double prevNumber2 = 1;
    double fib = 0;

    for(int i =0; i < number; i++){
        fib = prevNumber1;
        prevNumber1 = prevNumber2;
        prevNumber2 = fib + prevNumber2;

}
    return fib;
}
```

The code above is what I have.

Following is the error I keep on getting:

```
 error: cannot find symbol
 System.out.printf("Fibonacci #%d is %d\n",number, fibcalc(fib));
                                                              ^
 symbol:   variable fib
 location: class dlin_Fibonacci
```

It is saying that it cannot find 
    `fibcalc(fib)`

I want to return the value of `fib` from my `fibcalc` method, so I can print it in my `main` method.

Does anyone know why it is not letting me?

I attempted in using just the variable `fib`, but the result is the same error message.
Does this have to do with the fact that variable `fib` is a local variable and not a class variable? If it is, then how do make it a class variable? 
I tried moving the variable `fib` and `number` above my `main` method. Something like...

```
private static int number = 0;
private static double fib = 0;

public static void main(String arg[])
```

However, this gave me error: `illegal start of an expression` for the variables.

Also, can someone tell me if I am doing the return statement right?

I did some research into that going to varies sites watching videos. It seem like I followed every step. However I still don't under what it mean by "passing the parameter"
which is the variable inside of the () within a method. does that variable comes from other method or is it just created within the method that is written? like my example above, will the variable`int number` be passed from my `main` method to my `fibcalc` method simply by stating it in within the ()?

Comment: You might want to add a tag corresponding to the actual language you're using instead of one of the useless overgeneralized tags.

Comment: also you might wanna put the return statement into the method you are using, else you won't return anything

Comment: add java tag* and what do you mean by putting the return statement into the method i am using? It is not in the `fibcalc` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fib`is not in scope since it's local to `fibcalc`. Change the line like this:

```
 System.out.printf("Fibonacci #%d is %d\n",number, fibcalc(number));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. I also had to change the second `%d` into a `%f` because of the format specifier. However could you explain why I have to use `fibcalc(number)` instead of `fibcalc(fib)` ? I thought that the varaible inside of the () is what I want from `fibcalc`methed to return.

Comment: No, the variable inside the parenthesis is the argument you want to pass to the method. `fib` is a local variable declared inside `fibcalc`, and with `return fib` you say that you want to return the value of `fib`. If you later want to reuse the value in `main`, you have to assign it to another variable like this: `double result = fibcalc(number)`.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ways to solve this, first:

```
System.out.printf("Fibonacci #%d is %d\n",number, fibcalc((int)fib));
```

or the second way:

```
public static double fibcalc(double number)
```

:)

Comment: did not work, still getting the same error. I tried with the frist way then the 2nd way you suggested then both together. none worked. still getting the same old error. `error: cannot find symbol System.out.printf("Fibonacci #%d is %d\n",number, fibcalc(fib)); ^ symbol: variable fib location: class dlin_Fibonacci 1 error` I sure it is the fact that for some reason my `main` method can not call upon my `fibcalc` method

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, the issue has to do with the scope of `fib`, not ints versus doubles.

Comment: @user1714873 stranger here I got the same error, but the problem was solved with both ways, maybe the Vucan have reason, the 'private static double fib = 0;' is on same class?

Comment: well actually I didn't declare my variable `fib` as a class method and  maybe that was why.